# Try to fill null values with mean number..but why it showing error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, fillna

```
def fun1(x):
    if x['Total_Stops'] == 'non-stop':
        
return x['Price'].fillna(5024.90)
    elif x['Total_Stops'] == '1 stop':
        return x['Price'].fillna(10594.12)
    elif x['Total_Stops'] == '2 stops':
        return x['Price'].fillna(12712.36)
    elif x['Total_Stops'] == '3 stops':
        return x['Price'].fillna(13112)
    elif x['Total_Stops'] == '4 stops':
        return x['Price'].fillna(17686)
    else:
        return x['Price']


df['Price'] = df.apply(fun1, axis = 1)
```

i want fill na values with this numbers ..but it showing error  AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'fillna'

can anyone answer this.

Try to get answer my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

For an efficient approach, use a dictionary to map your values:

```
d = {'non-stop': 5024.90, '1 stop': 10594.12,
     '2 stops': 12712.36, '3 stops': 13112,
     '3 stops': 17686}

m = df['Price'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'Price'] = df.loc[m, 'Total_Stops'].map(d)
```

Variant:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].fillna(df['Total_Stops'].map(d))
```